# Applying OSM styles to vector MBTILES on QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

I downloaded [here](https://data.maptiler.com/downloads/europe/) the OpenStreetMap vector tiles (mbtiles format) from MapTiler. Now I uploaded the file to QGIS but I see it without styles. How can I apply the standard OSM styles to it?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few repos around on Gitlab with various style file options. Making a copy of these repos, and then loading up the appropriate styles in QGIS for each layer should work.

I had downloaded the shapefile data for areas of OSM data I was interested in via [geofabrik](https://download.geofabrik.de/) and had success by using the style files in this repo: https://github.com/mkoenigb/OSM-Geofabrik_Universal-QML-Style

Other repos to consider include:

- https://github.com/3liz/osm-in-qgis/tree/master
- https://github.com/charleyglynn/OSM-Shapefile-QGIS-stylesheets/tree/master

Comment: In the coming weeks I will take up this task and try your solution. Please message me again if you see that I do not reply (I must have forgotten!).